# how to prevent a button from moving when clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have several buttons within a div that once clicked will display a value.  The issue that I am having is: once a button is clicked and displays a value, it also shifts down. I am unsure about how to prevent this from happening. Can anyone help?  Here is a link to the example that I am creating:
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJzROE

```
<div id="gamebox">
<input type="button" id="one" onclick="clickBtn('one')"/>
<input type="button" id="two" onclick="clickBtn('two')"/>
<input type="button" id="three" onclick="clickBtn('three')"/>
<input type="button" id="four" onclick="clickBtn('four')"/>
<input type="button" id="five" onclick="clickBtn('five')"/>
<input type="button" id="six" onclick="clickBtn('six')"/>
<input type="button" id="seven" onclick="clickBtn('seven')"/>
<input type="button" id="eight" onclick="clickBtn('eight')"/>
<input type="button" id="nine" onclick="clickBtn('nine')"/>
</div>
#gamebox
{
height:460px;
width:460px;
border:2px solid red;
}
input
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
font-size:60px;
}
var player= 1;
function clickBtn(btn){
if(player == 1){
document.getElementById(btn).value = "X";
document.getElementById(btn).disabled = "disabled";
player -=1;
}
else {
document.getElementById(btn).value = "O";
document.getElementById(btn).disabled = "disabled";
player +=1;
}
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything moving in FF43?

Comment: @Storm - I see your problem. Just one question, do you have to use buttons? :) Else we can use something else like divs and ill draw you something cool.

Comment: @FrederikMoller - yea I can use something else.  I am just trying my best to keep the code simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some minor adjustments to your CSS input definition will help force the dimensions to a specific height.

```
input
{
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Updated Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbNjXg

Comment: @Axel- amazing fix and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem, but it seems like it behaves differently in different browsers.

A CodePen link for you: http://codepen.io/FredM7/pen/adZEor

By using 'divs' we can allow ourselves to style the elements more easily and therefore create a better-looking game.

HTML:

```
<div id="gamebox">
  <div id="one"  class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('one');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="two"  class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('two');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="three" class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('three');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="four" class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('four');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="five" class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('five');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="six"  class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('six');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="seven" class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('seven');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="eight" class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('eight');"><span></span></div>
  <div id="nine" class="input enabled" onclick="InputClick('nine');"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

You will notice that I also have a span element in there.
What is this for??

The span is to allow us to center an element (in this case, span), without having to know how high or how wide it is - essentially centering an element with unknown height and width. This span will contain our X or O.

CSS:

```
#gamebox
{
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.input
{
  font-size: 40px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.33333333333333% - 2px);
  height: calc(33.33333333333333% - 2px);
  background: #505050;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.input:hover
{
  background: #909090;
}

.input span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
```

100 / 3 = 33.33333333333333

Because we have 3 elements vertically and 3 horizontally, we may want to make this dynamic as possible. By dynamic I mean that to change the size of the gamebox, all we need to do is to change the size of 'gamebox', and everything else will just resize and fit in there.

JS:

```
var player = true;

function InputClick(id){
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if(HasClass(element, "enabled")) { //Disable
    element.className = "input disabled";
    if (player) {
      element.firstChild.innerHTML = "X";
    } else {
      element.firstChild.innerHTML = "O"; 
    }
    player = !player;

    //
    //Perform other game logic here, like checking win/lose.
    //
  }
}

function HasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

The JS handles the player turns, and also changes the class of the element and therefore does not perform a change when it cannot find the 'enabled' class, therefore behaving like a 'disabled button'.

Again, I did not try to use buttons, but for me personally, using divs is just so much easier in the long-run.

I hope this helps :).